# Type assertion on function ecdsa.Verify

Tags: go

Here is the code:

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "crypto/ecdsa"
        "crypto/elliptic"
        "crypto/rand"
        "fmt"
    )
    
    func main() {
        msg := "Any random message"
        curve := elliptic.P224()
        key, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(curve, rand.Reader)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        r, s, err := ecdsa.Sign(rand.Reader, key, []byte(msg))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        // fmt.Println("r: ", r)
        // fmt.Println("s: ", s)
    
        publicKey := key.Public()
        isVerified := ecdsa.Verify(publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey), []byte(msg), r, s)
        fmt.Println("isVerified: ", isVerified)
        fmt.Println("key.PublicKey: ", key.PublicKey)
        fmt.Println("key.D: ", key.D)
    
        fmt.Println("key.Public() : ", publicKey)
        fmt.Printf("Type of publicKey: %T\n", publicKey)//*ecdsa.PublicKey
    }
```

Why do I need a type assertion when calling `ecdsa.Verify()` on `publicKey`?

When I print the type of `publicKey`, it says clearly that it is type `*ecdsa.PublicKey`, the type wanted by the respective function argument, but instead it is interpreted as type `crypto.PublicKey`.

This is the error message:

```
./main.go:25:28: cannot use publicKey (type crypto.PublicKey) as type *ecdsa.PublicKey in argument to ecdsa.Verify: need type assertion
```

Comment: checked it on playground, runs correctly. did you rebuild it?

Comment: ecdsa crypto module, like others, implements the crypto.Signer interface. https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#Signer So it must return a crypto.PublicKey and not its module type.

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed in the docs:

- [ecdsa.PrivateKey.Public](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PrivateKey.Public) returns a [crypto.PublicKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#PublicKey)
- [ecdsa.Verify](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#Verify) wants a [ecdsa.PublicKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/ecdsa/#PublicKey)

The two types are completely different:

- `crypto.PublicKey` is an interface: it contains a concrete value and a dynamic type. At compile time, the type could be anything, so it must be checked (type switch, type assertion) at runtime
- `ecdsa.PublicKey` is a concrete type

The entire point of interfaces is to accept **any type** that implements the interface. In your case, `publicKey` could have dynamic type `ecdsa.PublicKey`, or `rsa.PublicKey`, or even `nil`. The compiler allows them all.

When it comes to calling a function or method requiring a specific type, the compiler will now require the actual type requested. This can be done using a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements).

You may find it unnecessary in your simple example but consider adding a few intermediaries between key generation and verification (such as allowing different types of keys) and you may end up with different underlying types for the key (one is `ecdsa.PublicKey`, the other is `rsa.PublicKey`). The `crypto.PublicKey` interface allows passing this key around easily but when it comes to actually using it, **you must check the dynamic type**.

Finally: the reason you are seeing `*ecdsa.PublicKey` when printing with the `%T` verb is that [print calls reflect.TypeOf](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?#L653). Per the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf), this is the dynamic type of the passed-in interface (or `nil`).